# Does fusion "add" the ages of the participants?

Tags: steven-universe

Typically, when two people (gems or otherwise) fuse in *Steven Universe*, they seem to end up with characteristics that are in some sense a combination or intermediate between the two participants, such as Garnet's electrokinesis arising from the interaction between Ruby's fire and Sapphire's ice.

However, in refence to the fusion of Steven and Greg (Steg), the wiki [claims](https://steven-universe.fandom.com/wiki/Steg) (without citation) that:

> Steg's overall appearance resembles that of a man in his middle
> adulthood due to Steven and Greg's ages, of 16 and 42 respectively,
> combining into one.

It also lists his age as 58, presumably following the same logic. The article for Stevonnie similarly lists their age as being the sum of Steven and Connie's ages.

On the other hand, it is true that Stevonnie consistently looks older than either Steven or Connie individually, although this could perhaps be attributed to fusion generally leading to an increase in physical size.

Is it the case that when Steven fuses with a human, their apparent ages "add," rather than "averaging" the ages of the two people fusing?